# How can I mock my generic Unity resolve wrapper? Getting call is ambiguous

Tags: c#, unity-container, moq

```
public T Resolve<T>() {
  return _container.Resolve<T>();
}
```

and

```
Mock<ServiceLocator> serviceLocator = new Mock<ServiceLocator>();
Mock<SecurityHelper> securityHelper= new Mock<SecurityHelper>();
serviceLocator.Setup(x => x.Resolve<SecurityHelper>()).Returns(securityHelper);
```

Produces this error, how can I get around this?

> Error 36  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   '`Moq.Language.IReturns<MVCWebsite.Helpers.ServiceLocator,MVCWebsite.Helpers.SecurityHelper>.Returns(System.Func<MVCWebsite.Helpers.SecurityHelper>)`'
>   and
>   '`Moq.Language.IReturns<MVCWebsite.Helpers.ServiceLocator,MVCWebsite.Helpers.SecurityHelper>.Returns(MVCWebsite.Helpers.SecurityHelper)`' C:\dev\Foundation\Foundation.Test\Fixtures\Account\AccountCtrlFixture.cs    61  13  Foundation.Test

**Edit: (Below is the final working solution, after following Sergey's help)**

```
[Test]
        public void TestResolveMockPoc()
        {
            //Mock service locator object
            Mock<ServiceLocator> serviceLocator = new Mock<ServiceLocator>();

            //Mock appSettings object
            Mock<AppSettings> appSettings = new Mock<AppSettings>();
            appSettings.Object.AppName = "IfYouSeeThisPocIsWorking";

            //Mock Resolve method to return my mocked object, for this particular type.
            serviceLocator.Setup(x => x.Resolve<AppSettings>()).Returns(appSettings.Object);

            //Override ServiceLocator inside the ServiceLocator helper (this is what is called by actual project)
            ServiceLocator.Locator = serviceLocator.Object;

            //Assert if this Moq Poc worked :-) ;)
            string updatedAppName = ServiceLocator.AppSettings().AppName;
            Assert.AreEqual(ServiceLocator.AppSettings().AppName, "IfYouSeeThisPocIsWorking");


        }
```

Comment: You probably need to cast `null`: `Returns((SecurityHelper)null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two `Returns` methods defined on mock setup which require single argument:

```
 IReturnsResult<TMock> Returns(TResult value);
 IReturnsResult<TMock> Returns(Func<TResult> valueFunction);
```

First one simple accepts value which should be returned by mocked method. Second one accepts function which should be called to calculate returned value. Compiler just can't decide what you are trying to do - pass `null` as `SecurityHelper` instance, or as `Func` delegate instance. So, simply cast `null` value to appropriate type to help compiler choose:

```
serviceLocator.Setup(x => x.Resolve<SecurityHelper>())
              .Returns((SecurityHelper)null);
```

NOTES: If you wonder what is `TResult` in above methods, it is type which returns `Func` expression passed to setup:

```
 ISetup<TResult> Setup<TResult>(Expression<Func<TResult>> expression)
```

I.e. that is type of value returned by mocked method. In your case it will be type returned by `Resolve<SecurityHelper>()` call.

UPDATE: After your edit - you are trying to return value of type `Mock<SecurityHelper>`. But `Returns` expects `TResult` to be of type `SecurityHelper` (see above notes why). So, you need to pass mocked object instance `securityHelper.Object`.

Comment: Hi Sergey, thanks again! Sorry, how can I get it to return my mocked object. (have changed code above)

Comment: @Baconbeastnz hi, sorry, didn't see your edit. Updated answer for your original question and for updated

Comment: Apologies for the edit. That's brilliant, thank you :)!

Comment: @Baconbeastnz welcome :) I added more details to answer and hope it is more helpful now

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need to do is return the object associated with your Mock SecurityHelper:

```
serviceLocator.Setup(x => x.Resolve<SecurityHelper>())
              .Returns<SecurityHelper>(securityHelper.Object);
```